# If I add a lagged dependent variable, do I need to add the lagged independent variables too?

Tags: time-series, econometrics, dynamic-regression

If I have a normal regression model

```
y_t = βx_t + ε_t
```

and want to add a y_(t-1), would this be proper?

```
y_t = ρΔy_(t-1) + βx_t + ε_t
```

or would I need to also add the lagged x, like this?

```
y_t = ρΔy_(t-1) + βx_t + θΔx_(t-1) + ε_t
```

Comment: what type of data you want to analyse ? time series , cross section , eperimental etc .,? why do you want to do something like this ?

Comment: I'm analyzing macro time series like interest rates, savings rates etc. I want

Comment: Sorry, accidentally pressed enter. I want to add the y-variable because I'm pretty sure it's significant.

Comment: The savings rate (y-variable) in the previous period should affect the savings rate in the current period

Comment: IA good point.. I am not aware of how  did you construct your independent variables.  Also you have not mentioned type of data and research design.

Comment: How I constructed the independent variables? They're basically just real interest rates over time in a single country. As for research design, I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: Apparently,  your data is historical. For how many years or months. Is it monthly or annual  and without  missing year/month. How many observations.

Comment: Oh, I see. The data stretches from the 1960's to 2017 with quarterly frequency (about 220-230 observations), no missing quarters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69963/discussion-between-subhash-c-davar-and-chisq).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question ,  comments and the discussion taken together indicate that  you should use the multiple regression analysis that incorporates lagged dependent variable and other independent variable (variables)in your model. Whether it is proper to use lagged dependent as a n independent variable ? Yes, if there a valid reason. Generally, the past/antecedents affect the present outcome. A lag of x  - the independent variable, (along with) should not be used as one of independent variables. We may use lag of independent variable in place of  current values if the  stronger relation (with dependent variable) vis with  current values can be postulated.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, it is not necessary to add a lagged x just because I add a lagged y?

Comment: You may ask another question if you want an answer to your imagination/fantasy.

Comment: Actually this was my original question if you see the title again.

Comment: Once you decide to introduce a lagged of dependent variable, there is no need to add lagged independent variable too.

Comment: many a thanks for your appreciation. was it for a doctoral thesis ?

Comment: It's for my bachelor thesis actually. Haha

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69989/discussion-between-subhash-c-davar-and-chisq).